# Trap command in UNIX

Tags: linux, shell, unix, signals

How does the trap command work in this code?

```
trap "ignore" 2
ignore()    
{
    main
}
main()
{
trap "main" 2
 while [ 1 ]
do
    echo -e "\t\t\t1.Add\n\t\t\t2.Remove\n\t\t\t3.Edit\n\t\t\t4.Search\n\t\t\t5.Display\n\t\t\t6.Exit"
    echo "Enter the option"
    read option
    case $option in
    1)echo "You take add option";;
    2)echo "You take Remove option";;
    3)echo "You take Edit option";;
    4)echo "You take Search option";;
    5)echo "You take Display option";;
    6)exit;;
    *)echo "Invalid Option"
    esac
done
}

main
```

If the above script is executed, the ctrl+c signal is trapped and the main function is called. But, it is done only only time(first time). It does not work in second time. At first time of ctrl+c, main will be called. But, this works only once. At second time of the ctrl+c, main will not be executed.

Answer (score 4):

That's how signals work in UNIX. When you send a SIGINT using by pressing <kbd>ctrl + C</kbd>, the signal handler is called i.e. in your case, the `main` function. But when the handler is processing the signal, all the subsequent signals are *blocked* until the handler returns. In your case, the handler never returns. So your program can't react to the subsequent SIGINT signals until the handler returns. It's not a good idea to call a signal handler recursively and a signal handler shouldn't do too much of work either. It should process the signal and return as soon as it can.

Also, note that the defined macro names such as `SIGINT` should be used for better portability than the actual numbers. You can get the list using `kill -l` or `trap -l` commands.

Comment: So, what is the way for my expected output?

Comment: I thought I answered that :) Basically subsequent signals are blocked because the first time the signal handler is called, it never returns.